# How to get screen not to jump back to up when clicking div to open

Tags: javascript

i got page with multiple open/hide divs and the problem here is that everytime i try to click one to open or hide the screen jumps at the top of the page..

Anyone idea how to fix this? Javascript is used to hide divs.

Thanks!

---

```
$(function() {
$('a.hide').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.hideable').find('.hide-container').toggle();
});

$('a#hide-all').click(function() {
    $('.hide-container').hide();
});

 $('.hide-container').hide(); });
```

Comment: Are you using links with `href="#"` and forgetting to return `false` from your onclick handler(s)?  Because it sounds like that's what is happening.

Comment: yeah, seems so i try change those

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using `href="#"`, don't do that, [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) instead.

Comment: That's pretty severe diminishing returns there, given that the suggested replacement for `<a href="window.print()">Print</a>` is some two-dozen lines, all so that the 2 people in the world who have JavaScript turned off don't see a "Print" link that they can't use.  I'd sooner add a `<noscript>Turn your JavaScript back on, silly</noscript>` than jump through that many hoops just to hide a link.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using an A tag to open close the DIV’s, it means that in Javascript you’ll need to disable the default action for the A tag.

In jquery for example:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: althought it seems it disables all the other links